# Dynamically select and update a column value in LINQ resultset

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-sql, dynamic-linq

I have a scenario in which there exists a LINQ resultset; I used the following query

```
var stockDetails = from d in db.BloodBanks
                   where d.bbUserName == Session["username"].ToString()
                   select d;
```

Now I want to use this resultset and update a column's value. The column is being selected dynamically via a string variable.

The code which I am trying to use is:

```
foreach (BloodBank b in stockDetails)
            {
                b.<--column name from string variable--> = TextBox1.Text;
            }
```

Please help me out here as to how do I achieve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use reflection to get the field by name like this.

```
foreach (BloodBank b in stockDetails)
{
    FieldInfo f = typeof(BloodBank).GetField("fieldName");
    if (f != null)
    {
       f.SetValue(b, TextBox1.Text);
    }
}
```

Comment: nah it doesnt seems to work. I replaced the `fieldName` with the sting variable which contains the column name. but finally the `db.SubmitChanges();` isn't updating the values.

Comment: after analyzing the values I found out that the code `FieldInfo f = typeof(BloodBank).GetField("fieldName");` returns `null` in f.

Comment: @Piyush @Bala why go to the Field, why not got to the Property and get the Get method or Set method?

Comment: to be very frank I have no idea about reflection. all I know is that `FieldInfo` is returning `null` in `f`. Tried with `PropertyInfo` but in the line `f.SetValue(b, TextBox.Text);` it asks for 3rd parameter too for which if I set `null` then gives me an error saying `cant be converted to nullable.`

Comment: Can you post a little bit of the class BloodBank and the property/field you are trying to set?

Comment: @Bala @SamSaffron Thaks a lot guys for your answers. Instead of `FieldInfo`, I used `PropertyInfo` and it was just a mere `sting to int32` coversion which was creating the problems with `PropertyInfo`.

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach (BloodBank b in db.BloodBanks.Where(d => where d.bbUserName == Session["username"].ToString())
{
    b.col = TextBox1.Text;
}
```

Comment: @Pyiush Cool, If I may ask, why won't it work in your situation?

Comment: Since I wanted to select a particular column which is stored in a string variable. In your case you selected `col` which does not exist in my database. actually wanted something like `b."dynamic_column_name" = TextBox1.Text;`