# How do I update single field value using Reflection in LINQ

Tags: linq, dynamic, reflection, lambda, insert-update

I receive two variables from the client postback which match 'fieldname' and a 'value'.  The fieldname could be one of 50 fields I have within a db table column.

How would I use reflection to identify which postback fieldname matches the field in the table and then update that single field with the value passed back using a LINQ update ?

```
(string fieldid, string fieldvalue)
```

***update:***  I've looked at [Dynamically select and update a column value in LINQ resultset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5993889/dynamically-select-and-update-a-column-value-in-linq-resultset)

and instead of setting a specific TExtBox on page, I need to write back to the db the value of the reflected variable field?  This is where I am looking to learn more.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamically select and update a column value in LINQ resultset](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5993889/dynamically-select-and-update-a-column-value-in-linq-resultset)

Comment: Wat do you mean by 'LINQ update'? LINQ is a query language used to 'query', not to update.

Comment: yes, sorry... normally, I'd query a row from a db something like this:

**var query = from d in connection.Get<AGlobal.user>().ToList()
            where d.username == AUsername 
            select d;**

Then set a few field variables and update using:  

**connection.Update<AGlobal.user>(query);**

Comment: Where the connection.Get  and the connection.Update are already class methods.

Comment: The question you 'looked at' doesn't **set** the textbox, but sets the database field called 'fieldname' to the contents of the textbox, so t works the same if you replace textbox.Text with a variable.

Comment: Thank you sgnoore, yep, I should have studied it closer. The example given goes as far as to set the fieldname value.. I was looking for an example that would show me a way to write to the db the value of a field where the name was not pre-known.

As it is, I have created a Switch case set so that I can identify the 1 of many fields that could be a postback and write the content value to the correct field in the db.  Was hoping for a more condense code solution.

Answer (score 1):

If neither your source nor destination names are known at compile type then you can use reflection to both read and set the values , eg  something like

```
public void SetField<T1, T2>(T1 destination, string destinationFieldName, 
                             T2 source     , string sourceFieldName)
{  
    FieldInfo destFi    = typeof(T1).GetField(destinationFieldName);
    FieldInfo sourceFi  = typeof(T2).GetField(sourceFieldName);

    if (sourceFi != null && destFi != null)
        destFi.SetValue(destination, sourceFi.GetValue(source));
}
```

then if you are trying to copy a field called NewName from settings (which is instance of a class called Settings) to a the column name of record which is of type Table1, then you can do :

```
SetField<Table1, Settings<(record , "Name" , settings , "NewName");
```

If you are using properties rather than fields, then you need to use PropertyInfo rather than FieldInfo

```
public void SetProperty<T1, T2>(T1 destination, string destinationFieldName, 
                                T2 source, string sourceFieldName)
{
    PropertyInfo destPi     = typeof(T1).GetProperty(destinationFieldName);
    PropertyInfo sourcePi  = typeof(T2).GetProperty(sourceFieldName);

    if (sourcePi != null && destPi != null)
        destPi.SetValue(destination, sourcePi.GetValue(source , null) , null);
}
```

Obviously there is a performance hit using something like this.

Comment: thanks for your imput - its certainly more compact and flexible than what I am using currently. I shall run tests on both to consider the performance hit.